# Работа с бинарными файлами с++

Tags: c++

Как считать и записать информацию из бинарного файла в другой бинарный файл средствами fstream фигня выходит при чтении ...

```
ifstream in("d://1.txt",ios::binary|ios::in); //Открываем файл в двоичном режиме только для чтения
int i=0;
string str;
while ((i = in.get()) != -1) {
    str+=i;
}
in.close();
```

так же проблема в том, что я незнаю сколько будет строк в файле

Comment: Покажите конкретный код, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: добавил код ....

Comment: Читайте не в int и потом string, а в unsigned char[1024]. Потом сравнивайте прочитанные байты с реально содержащимися в файле. Когда будет расхождение - можно будет говорить об ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

Ну и зачем из *бинарного* файла читать *строки* - они же не для этого!
Прочитал некоторое количество байтов и записал - и всё.

А ещё у тебя путь к файлу прописан неверно, впрочем, должно и с ним работать.

Comment: Я как-то видел в трое, как они что-то типа std::string использовали именно для бинарных данных.

Comment: Прочитал некоторое количество байтов меня не устраивает как считать весь файл разом я не знаю сколько в нем

Comment: ifstream file ("d://1//1.png", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    buffer = new char [file.tellg()];
  file.read(buffer,file.tellg());



  file.close();

Comment: так тоже не считывает ... тупо ошибка

Comment: @Study814, ты `//` на ``\\`` замени уже всё-таки.

Comment: они читает файл так (пробывал на текстовом) уже с данной проблемой вроде разобрался встала другая . Как например прочитать картинку а потом переписать ее в другой файл

Answer (score 2):

А чем не подходит тривиальный код

```
  char c;
  while (in.get(c))
    out.put(c);
```

???

Он ведь почти один в один соответствует идеоматическому копированию из K&R

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
  fputc(c, out);
```